# Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:cors:zip:1.3.0

Tags: grails, cors

i need some help. Am trying to add cors to grails 2.4 so that i can allow cross-domain and have frontend application run from different domain(angular framework).
I found out https://github.com/davidtinker/grails-cors and followed the instructions in the README file, and when i run grails command ***./grailsw clean***  I run into errors below.

***| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:cors:zip:1.3.0 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:cors:zip:1.3.0 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:cors:zip:1.3.0 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:cors:zip:1.3.0 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:cors:zip:1.3.0***

I added this to my BuildConfig.groovy file, What could i have done wrong?

`plugins { compile ":cors:1.3.0" }`

Answer (score -1):

Grails 2.4.x is really, really outdated... (I also still maintain an old grails app, will switch to 4 or 5 in the next weeks ...) The only solution I can think off is, to clone the repository and build it as your own grails-plugin and install it in your local maven repository (grails maven-install).

Comment: "The only solution I can think off is, to clone the repository and build it as your own grails-plugin and install it in your local maven repository" - Another options is to add  `mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"` as a repository in `BuildConfig.groovy`.  There are other problems in the linked project, but adding that repository will fix the problem described in the question.